# Laravel 4 Response

Tags: json, laravel-4

how to return response in laravel 4 like for this example ?

```
"key": {
    "q1": "a3",
    "q2": "a2",
    "q3": "a1"
}
```

I do simple response

```
$key = KeyV2::all();

        return Response::json(array(
            'key' => $key
        ), 200);
```

result is

```
"key": {
    "name": "q1",
    "value": "a3"
}
```

but I need as I have described above.

I know that when I do ALL () it returns to me in this collection does not necessarily write toArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lists()` for that:

```
$key = KeyV2::lists('value', 'key');
return Response::json(array(
    'key' => $key
));
```

(And `200` is unnecessary since it is the default value)